# Maui multiple RadiobuttonGroup not working

Tags: c#, maui

I have a test project with two radio button groups. The first group on the page will not show the radio button that should be selected when the page loads. The sample project below demonstrates the problem.

The form has two rows of radio buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="RadioButtonGroupTest.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="0"
            Padding="30,30,0,0"
            VerticalOptions="Start">

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition
                        Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition
                        Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition
                        Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition
                        Width="5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label
                    Text="Group 1"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"></Label>

                <HorizontalStackLayout
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="Group1">

                    <RadioButton
                        x:Name="Group1YesRadioButton"
                        Content="Yes"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=Group1YesChecked}"
                        Value="Yes">
                    </RadioButton>

                    <RadioButton
                        x:Name="Group1NoRadioButton"
                        Content="No"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=Group1NoChecked}"
                        Value="No">
                    </RadioButton>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>

                <Label
                    Text="Group 2"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"></Label>

                <HorizontalStackLayout
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="Group2">

                    <RadioButton
                        x:Name="Group2RedRadioButton"
                        Content="Red"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=Group2RedChecked}"
                        Value="Red">
                    </RadioButton>

                    <RadioButton
                        x:Name="Group2GreenRadioButton"
                        Content="Green"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=Group2GreenChecked}"
                        Value="Green">
                    </RadioButton>

                    <RadioButton
                        x:Name="Group2BlueRadioButton"
                        Content="Blue"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=Group2BlueChecked}"
                        Value="Bule">
                    </RadioButton>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

The view model has 5 boolean values:

```
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public bool Group1YesChecked { get; set; }
        public bool Group1NoChecked { get; set; }
        public bool Group2RedChecked { get; set; }
        public bool Group2GreenChecked { get; set; }
        public bool Group2BlueChecked { get; set; }

        public ViewModel() 
        { 
            Group1YesChecked = true;
            Group1NoChecked = false;
            Group2RedChecked = false;
            Group2GreenChecked = true;
            Group2BlueChecked = false;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

The code behind for the page sets the view model:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = vm;
    }
}
```

[main page display when application is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nAgq.png)

What am I doing wrong?

I expected the Yes button to be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem in my project. And this problem only appeared on the windows platform. Even though I set its value as true directly, it will not work either.

```
<RadioButton
   x:Name="Group1YesRadioButton"
   Content="Yes"
   IsChecked="True"
   Value="Yes">
</RadioButton>
```

And I found it is a known issue on the github. You can follow up this issue about [RadioButton GroupName and IsChecked properties work inconsistently on Windows](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7595).

Comment: Thanks for that github reference. Looks like there has been no movement on this so I guess I will have to implement my own Radio Button Group. Bugger...